# Lenovo Z50-75 80EC | QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter | Not working

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, lenovo, atheros

Currently my wireless does not seem to want to work for me, and it looks like I have an active driver listed when running lshw command;

```
  zero@zero-Lenovo-Z50-75:~$ sudo lshw -C network
 *-network
    description: Network controller
    product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: 20
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
    resources: irq:35 memory:f0800000-f09fffff
```

And everything looks okay from what I can tell when running lspci and lsmod commands

```
  zero@zero-Lenovo-Z50-75:~$ lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
```

.

```
zero@zero-Lenovo-Z50-75:~$ lsmod | grep ath
 ath10k_pci             45056  0
 ath10k_core           311296  1 ath10k_pci
 ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
 mac80211              737280  1 ath10k_core
 cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

I pulled a little more information as well

```
 zero@zero-Lenovo-Z50-75:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
     Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3545]
     Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
```

.

```
 zero@zero-Lenovo-Z50-75:~$ uname -r
 4.4.0-21-generic
```

I am running on a freshly installed version of 16.04, and have gone through the Wireless Troubleshooting guide, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices, with no real success, but was able to at least pull off of this information. Anyone have any ideas on how I can get wireless to work on this device?

***UPDATE***
Ran the requested command and received the following

```
zero@zero-Lenovo-Z50-75:~$ dmesg | grep ath
[   14.158205] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   14.416562] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   14.800570] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin failed with error -2
[   16.012966] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid fd35c83e-b588-42c9-8b35-9732809f4865)
[   16.012996] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6164 hw2.1 (0x05010000, 0x003405ff sub 17aa:3545) fw WLAN.RM.1.1-00141 fwapi 5 bdapi 1 htt-ver 0.0 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[   16.013002] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   16.013340] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware register dump:
[   16.013346] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [00]: 0x05010000 0x000015B3 0x000A012D 0x00955B31
[   16.013352] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [04]: 0x000A012D 0x00060330 0x00000016 0x89785006
[   16.013356] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [08]: 0x00000000 0x00400000 0x00400600 0x00000001
[   16.013361] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00931C61 0x00931C7D
[   16.013366] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [16]: 0x0096BDBC 0x009286B6 0x00000000 0x00000000
[   16.013370] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [20]: 0x400A012D 0x0040E2B0 0x00955A00 0x00404590
[   16.013375] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [24]: 0x809287D9 0x0040E310 0x7A508EF8 0xC00A012D
[   16.013380] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [28]: 0x809288D7 0x0040E340 0x00000000 0xFFF08040
[   16.013384] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [32]: 0x809290FE 0x0040E360 0x00400000 0x00400600
[   16.013389] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [36]: 0x80929205 0x0040E380 0x00000000 0x00400600
[   16.013394] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [40]: 0x40928024 0x0040E3B0 0x0040D3D0 0x0040D3D0
[   16.013398] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [44]: 0x00000000 0x0040E3D0 0x009BB001 0x00040020
[   16.013403] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [48]: 0x00401BF0 0x00000001 0x00404B9C 0x00400000
[   16.013407] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [52]: 0x40928024 0x0040E3B0 0x0040D3D0 0x0040D3D0
[   16.013416] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: [56]: 0xE5EEA500 0xB43332FF 0xE7B7BE94 0x100D76CF
[   17.008219] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to receive control response completion, polling..
[   18.008124] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: ctl_resp never came in (-110)
[   18.008132] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to connect to HTC: -110
[   18.086191] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not init core (-110)
[   18.086230] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: could not probe fw (-110)
[   18.792102] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: cannot restart a device that hasn't been started
```

******************UPDATE******************

```
 zero@zero-Lenovo-Z50-75:~$ dmesg | grep ath
 [   13.176301] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
 [   13.499398] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
 [   14.854563] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca6164 hw2.1 (0x05010000, 0x003405ff sub 17aa:3545) fw SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
 [   14.854570] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
 [   14.854757] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   14.931417] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
 [   14.931423] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
 [   14.931428] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
 [   14.931431] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
 [   15.070970] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
 [   29.218751] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
 [   89.179591] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

Sorry for the delay in reposting, took me a while to get to a hard-line connection. I ran through the commands recommended to update the ath10k drivers and we have lift off. I'm currently connected via WiFi with no issues so far. I'll try to follow up on this after 72 hours or so of use.

Comment: The message log will probably show which firmware is missing. Please run: `dmesg | grep ath` and then edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 Ran command and updated. Lots of errors and failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try different firmware. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware/QCA6174/hw2.1/
sudo cp *  /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/
sudo mv firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1  firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot and let us see again:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! here are my results